# Can't access my app deployed on an AKS cluster, from the azure public ip

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm very new to Cloud providers and I'm trying to setup a cluster on Azure.
I setup the infra with terraform, and I create a ResourceGroup, a static Azure PublicIP (sku basic), a Azure Load Balancer(sku basic, connected to the public ip, front end port: 80, backend port 3000)  and a AKS cluster.
With Skaffold I then deploy on the AKS cluster a ClusterIP ( port: 3000, targetPort: 3000 that selects the server pods), the server Deployment( which listens to port 3000) plus the secrets.

The deployment goes well and logging the server pods shows the app is running correctly and listening on por 3000, but when I try to access the server either with the address (`20.218.249.246:80/api` where `80` is the load balancer front end port and the`/api`is the base for the router) or the dns (fixit.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com:80/api) from the Azure console the connection fails after timeout.
I deployed a Kubernetes Load balancer to test the cluster and from its external ip I can indeed access the server.
looking in the troubleshot guides I see that the check on the cluster's load balancer passes as it uses a `Standard` load balancer, but I did create a `Basic` one in terraform.

load balance check
[image: troubleshooting check]
public ip
[image: public ip]
load balancer
[image: load balancer]
cluster
[image: cluster]
resource group
[image: resource group]

It would seem by the check that my cluster is not using the load balancer I created as the one it is using is Standard and the one I created is Basic.

Am I missing out something in setting up the cluster or the ip on Azure?
Many thanks for the help, here are the files

## resource group

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
    tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
    Team = "DevOps"
  }
}
```

## public ip

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public-ip" {
  name                = "fixit-public-ip"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  domain_name_label = "fixit"
  # sku = "Standard"
  # fixit.germanywestcentral.cloudapp.azure.com

}
```

## load balancer

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "load-balancer" {
  name                = "fixit-load-balancer"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  # sku = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "PublicIPAddress"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.public-ip.id
  }
  
  
}
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "address-pool" {
  name                = "fixit-backend-pool"
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.load-balancer.id
  
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "load-balancer-rule" {
  name = "fixit-load-balancer-rule"
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.load-balancer.id
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddress"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  # backend_port                   = 27017
  backend_port                   = 3000
  # disable_outbound_snat = true

}
```

## cluster

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "server_cluster" {
  name                = "server_cluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  dns_prefix          = "fixit"
  kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version
  # sku_tier = "Paid"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    min_count = 1
    max_count = 3
    # vm_size    = "standard_b2s_v5"
    vm_size    = "standard_e2bs_v5"
    type = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    enable_host_encryption = false
    # os_disk_size_gb = 30
    enable_node_public_ip = true
    
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    ssh_key {
        key_data = var.ssh_key
    }
  }
  network_profile {
      network_plugin = "kubenet"
      # load_balancer_sku = "standard"
    
  }
  
}
```

## cluster ip

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-clusterip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP cloud provider's load balancer
  selector:
    app: fixit-server-pod
  ports:
    - name: server-clusterip-service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000 # service port
      targetPort: 3000 # por on which the app is listening to
```

## server

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fixit-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fixit-server-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fixit-server-pod
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-secret
      containers:
        - name: fixit-server-container
          image: vinnytwice/fixit-server:dev
          imagePullPolicy: 'Always'
          env:
            # - name: SERVER_DEV_IMAGE_TAG
            #   value: 'dev'

            # server
            - name: APP_LISTENING_PORT
              value: '3000'
            - name: API_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: server-secret
                  key: api-key
            # stripe
            - name: STRIPE_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: stripe-secret
                  key: stripe-key
            # mongo db connection string
            - name: MONGO_USERNAME_K8S
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: mongo-username-k8s
                  name: server-secret

            - name: MONGO_HOSTNAME_K8S
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: mongo-hostname-k8s
                  name: server-secret

            - name: MONGO_PORT_K8S
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: server-secret
                  key: mongo-port-k8s

            # neo4j connection string
            - name: MONGO_DB_K8S
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: mongo-db-k8s
                  name: server-secret

            - name: NEO4J_AURA_URI
               valueFrom:
                 secretKeyRef:
                   key: neo4j-aura-uri
                   name: neo4j-secret
            - name: NEO4J_AURA_USERNAME
               valueFrom:
                 secretKeyRef:
                   key: neo4j-aura-username
                   name: neo4j-secret
            - name: NEO4J_AURA_PASSWORD
               valueFrom:
                 secretKeyRef:
                   key: neo4j-aura-password
                   name: neo4j-secret
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: '2Gi'
              cpu: '500m'
              # cpu: '1.0'
```

Comment: The issue seems to be with the service type if its clusterIp it should be getting an IP from the service CIDR of the kubernetes cluster which usually is  cluster internal reachable IP, either using service type loadbalancer which should create LB for you or an ingress object. Basically, you need to route to your app from internet.

Comment: I just sorted it out, the problem is that I don't have to create an azurem_lb but rather configure the one the gets created by default with the cluster either via a kubernetes_service in terraform using the kubernetes provider, or manually deploying it to the cluster. I chosen to do it in terraform as for the cluster you need to provide a service principal with network contributor rights to be able to configure the default load balancer. Plus you need to pass a reference to the resource group in which the cluster is created,  and the public ip address.

Comment: In terraform you can just pass the resources outputs out of the modules and input them to other modules which makes the whole process very easy.  Doing it manually requires you to keep track of the ip address,  as in the various tests i do destroy everything .

Comment: on thing dough, when I access the app with that IP address from the browser, it show the "Not secure" label,

Comment: also, I removed the identity block, for the azurerm_kubernetes_cluster from and added a service_principal block passing the service principal id and secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It was my setup of course. I wasn't installing any ingress controller so of course the ingress service wasn't working at all, the proper implementation is to install an ingress controller https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli, which hooks up the the internal cluster load balancer, so there is no need to create one. Now, the ingress controller will accept an ip address for the load balancer, but you have to create the `PublicIP` in the `node resource group` because is going to look for it there and not in the `resource group`, got it after checking the difference between the two here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks.

So the working configuration is now:

## main

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.1.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
    }
  }
  subscription_id   = var.azure_subscription_id
  tenant_id         = var.azure_subscription_tenant_id
  client_id         = var.service_principal_appid
  client_secret     = var.service_principal_password
}


provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "${module.cluster.host}"
  client_certificate = "${base64decode(module.cluster.client_certificate)}"
  client_key = "${base64decode(module.cluster.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(module.cluster.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${module.cluster.host}"
    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(module.cluster.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(module.cluster.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(module.cluster.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
}



module "cluster" {
  source = "./modules/cluster"
  location = var.location
  vm_size = var.vm_size
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  node_resource_group_name = var.node_resource_group_name
  kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version
  ssh_key = var.ssh_key
  sp_client_id = var.service_principal_appid
  sp_client_secret = var.service_principal_password
}




module "ingress-controller" {
  source = "./modules/ingress-controller"
  public_ip_address = module.cluster.public_ip_address
  depends_on = [
    module.cluster.public_ip_address
  ]
}
```

## cluster

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
    tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    Team = "DevOps"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "server_cluster" {
  name                = "server_cluster"
  ### choose the resource goup to use for the cluster
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  ### decide the name of the cluster "node" resource group, if unset will be named automatically 
  node_resource_group = var.node_resource_group_name
  dns_prefix          = "fixit"
  kubernetes_version = var.kubernetes_version
  # sku_tier = "Paid"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    min_count = 1
    max_count = 3
    vm_size = var.vm_size

    type = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    enable_host_encryption = false
    # os_disk_size_gb = 30
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id = var.sp_client_id
    client_secret = var.sp_client_secret
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    ssh_key {
        key_data = var.ssh_key
    }
  }
  network_profile {
      network_plugin = "kubenet"
      load_balancer_sku = "basic" 
    
  }
  http_application_routing_enabled = false
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.resource_group
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public-ip" {
  name                = "fixit-public-ip"
  location            = var.location
  # resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  resource_group_name = var.node_resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  domain_name_label = "fixit"
  # sku = "Standard"

depends_on = [
  azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.server_cluster
]
}
```

## ingress controller

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name      = "ingress-nginx"
  repository = "ingress-nginx"
  chart     = "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "default"

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy"
    value = "Local"
  }

  set {
    name = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = var.public_ip_address
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.annotations.service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"
    value = "/healthz"
  }
}
```

## ingress service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  # namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2$3$4
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    # - host: fixit.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com #dns from Azure PublicIP


### Node.js server
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80 

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /server(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-clusterip-service
            port:
              number: 80
...

other services omitted
```

Hope this can help getting the setup right.
Cheers.